# L is a context free language over {0, 1}, prove, disprove:

Tags: formal-languages, automata

cont...

L is a context free language over {0, 1}, prove, disprove: 
L1 is a CFL over {a, b}, where L1 is the language of all words from L, that 0 is converted to a and 1 is converted to bba.

Thanks (:

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm not sure how to approach it. Do I need to show a grammar in order to prove? How do I disprove? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $G$ be a context-free grammar for $L$. Let $\mathscr{N}$ be the set of non-terminal symbols of $G$. Then every production $\pi$ of $G$ has the form $N\to w$, where $N\in\mathscr{N}$ and $w\in(\mathscr{N}\cup\{0,1\})^*$. Let $\pi'$ be the production obtained from $\pi$ by changing every $0$ in $w$ to an $a$ and every $1$ in $w$ to $bba$. Let $G\,'$ be the grammar obtained from $G$ by replacing the terminal alphabet $\{0,1\}$ with $\{a,b\}$ and each production $\pi$ of $G$ by $\pi'$. Show that $G\,'$ is a context-free grammar that generates $L_1$.